# How do I check if an element is NOT empty with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if an element is empty and if another is NOT empty. The first part of the if works but how do I check if the `#dynamicForm` element is NOT empty?¨

This obviously doesn't work but I need something like it:

```
if ($("#formButton").is(':empty') && $("#dynamicForm").is(':notempty')) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: [Logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!))

Comment: `x.is(':not(:empty)')` or `! x.is(':empty')` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!$("#dynamicForm").is(':empty')){
     // code here...
}
```

Note the not operator (`!`) in front.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can check if the selected element is empty and negate it:

```
!$('#dynamicForm').is(':empty')
```

Furthermore you can check if it's not empty with jquery selector `:not`:

```
$('#dynamicForm').is(':not(:empty)')
```

A third way would be to select all elements, that are not empty and check the length of the jquery collection:

```
$('#dynamicForm').not(':empty').length
```

If you need this check in several places you can add your own function to jQuery:

```
$.fn.notEmpty = function() {
  return !$(this).is(':empty')
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
if($('#dynamicForm').notEmpty())
```

That isn't realy clean and it's not keeping with the jquery conventions. So better extend the selectors instead of extending the functions:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
  notEmpty:function(c) {
    return !$(c).is(':empty');
  }
});
```

Now you can use it very straightforward:

```
if($('#dynamicForm').is(':notEmpty'))
```